На удивление Кота(,) Арина не пришла
Эх, здравствуйте, ребят. Вот и мэтр вернулся. Нужна запятушонка?
На удивление Кота(,) Арина не пришла.

Привет, Кот. Ну, наверное, не "на удивление..." а "к удивлению..."?

Нужно так: Арина, к удивлению Кота, оказалась на удивление  непунктуальной.  Так и не пришла, зря он в подъезде мерз.

https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/i?id=489220dcb7ba09b9d13f9baf98d2b393400d247f-3911063-images-thumbs&n=13

А если использовать "на удивление Кота"?

Еще немного информации об удивительной падежной форме на удивление, в которой так легко заблудиться.

Нужно отличать наречие на удивление от падежной формы сущ. на удивление. Првильно: на удивление (кому) всем.  Это орф. словарь РАН.  Так практически все и пишут. https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/на+удивление+всем

Есть падежная форма существительного на удивление (кого?) например: На удивление Кота никто не обращал внимание.

Есть вводное сочетание на удивление, указанное в справочнике Фрамполь: На этот раз, на удивление, обошлось (В. Распутин).

Есть вводное сочетание по Розенталю: к удивлению (кого?).

Возможно ли обособление сочетания на удивление всем? Да, возможно, как и факультативное обособление любого обстоятельственного оборота (требуется доказательство):
Экзамен, на удивление всем, она сдала с блеском и, таким образом, стала первой девочкой поступившей в училище.
Сергей Садов,  1998


Мой окончательный ответ: К удивлению кота, Арина не пришла.
Но желающие могут доказать правомерность обособления падежной формы существительного на удивление кота. Желательно использовать грамматику, словари, справочники, примеры из классической литературы. Нежелательно —  современные тексты, "которых полно в Нацкорпусе".
Чувство языка у пользователей явно притупилось, и это как раз от большого количества примеров с разным написанием. На удивление или к удивлению, кому или кого — какая разница! Кому нужны эти тонкости, зачем словари и справочники? И так сойдет! Мы часто опасаемся влияния иноязычной лексики, но вот этот "пофигизм" как раз и представляет наибольшую опасность для нашей словесности.

А это немного юмора: Пианистка вместо «соль»
Нам сыграла «ля-бемоль».
Дирижёр ей — ни гу-гу.
Дирижёру пофигу.
Лишь рукой махнул: «Извольте,
Где хотите, ля-бемольте.
За такую за зарплату
Как еще играть сонату?»

Этот момент (произвольное расширение вводных слов до "вводных предложений") обговаривается в справочнике Фрамполь. Лень искать, но там говорится что-то вроде, что вводные слова могут быть расширены до вводных предложений по типу на удивление=>на удивление кота.

Материалы из словарей
Русский орфографический словарь
на удивление (кому; замечательный; в высшей степени)

Большой универсальный словарь русского языка
НА УДИВЛЕНИЕ 1, нареч., с оттенком разг.
1.0. В неожиданно большой, превосходящей ожидания степени.   
Син. <удивительно, необычайно>, очень, <чрезвычайно>.

На удивление громкий (ловкий, смелый, умный, смышлёный 
разг., скромный, высокий, лёгкий, хороший, плохой …). На 
удивление громко (смело, глупо, незаметно, быстро, медленно, 
легко, хорошо …). На удивление жарко (холодно, весело, плохо 
 …). □ Задача оказалась на удивление лёгкой. Лето пролетело 
 на удивление быстро. Нам здесь на уди


Правильно:
К удивлению Кота, Арина не пришла.
Пояснение

Обособляется вводное сочетание, выражающее чувство говорящего. Розенталь, § 25: Найдёнов, к изумлению Нагульного, в одну секунду смахнул с плеч кожанку (Ш);

Использование падежной формы на удивление в качестве вводного сочетания в данном предложении стилистически некорректно.  Обычно это невводное, употребляется в функции обстоятельства меры и степени, не обособляется.

Форма на удивление может использоваться в качестве вводного слова для эмоциональной оценки:  На удивление, Арина не пришла. Но такой вариант скорее возможен в предложениях другой структуры: На этот раз, на удивление, обошлось (В. Распутин); На удивление, в сарае оказалось тепло.


Статья по теме. Используется  "Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений» Остроумовой и Фрамполь".

Открываем справочник вводных слов Фрамполь, а там все уже написано:

НА УДИВЛЕНИЕ (-ЬЕ), наречие.

Употребляется в функции вводного в значении  удивление» (выражает эмоциональную оценку): На этот  Р03» на удивление, обошлось
(В.Распутин); «Видное лицо»  °&се засмеялось, но явно для проформы.
Оно, на удивление,  225  держалось независимо и смотрело на Марлена
Михайловы^  прицельным взглядом (В.Аксенов); Но, на удивление, ощу^щ
себя совершенно свежим - как хозяйка магического гребня  расчесавшаяся
всласть (С.Лукьяненко).
Невводное, употребляется в функции обстоятельства  меры и степени, не обособляется: Она была на редкость, на  удивление красива
(В.Шукшин).
Невводное, употребляется в функции сказуемого или  несогласованного определения, не обособляется: И вышло всем  на удивление
(Ф.Достоевский); Ну вот, изготовили альбом на  удивленье (П.Бажов).



В словаре нет заданного предложения. На удивление и на удивление Кота – это одно и то же? К тому же в словаре РАН дается управление Д.п.  (двойная связь) на удивление (кому?) Коту. Сравнить: к удивлению (кого?) Кота (Р .п.).

Все там хорошо, сотня примеров в нацкорпусе "на удивление Кота". Управление тут не при чем. Любое существительное может иметь при себе родительный падеж для обозначения принадлежности.
